# mapping a digraph across sectors of countries

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geography, geographics

Given a (9,9) matrix representing three countries (for example, the US, China, Russia), each one of which has three sectors (vertices/sectors {1, 2, 3) for the US; {4, 5, 6} for China; and {7,8,9} for Russia), I like to create a map of the directed linkages between all 9 sectors using the actual world map.

```
SeedRandom[01];
g={{1.09738, 0.0440055, 0.113012, 0.0436654, 0.0550311, 0.0365684, 
 0.0990232, 0.0550859, 0.0629618}, {0.0850364, 1.05189, 0.0803699, 
 0.0999457, 0.0846171, 0.115742, 0.078153, 0.111992, 
 0.0828957}, {0.0982489, 0.0712597, 1.07401, 0.0723417, 0.0431498, 
 0.0824737, 0.126777, 0.0569532, 0.0808742}, {0.089248, 0.114673, 
 0.135009, 1.10033, 0.0743107, 0.107282, 0.133689, 0.0850109, 
 0.0467125}, {0.0921911, 0.0582554, 0.0937256, 0.0535134, 1.10261, 
 0.0882558, 0.0366383, 0.154662, 0.0893078}, {0.0835567, 0.0541454, 
 0.0971447, 0.0458107, 0.132431, 1.08961, 0.0726788, 0.108789, 
 0.118664}, {0.0747554, 0.150188, 0.139565, 0.0936757, 0.132907, 
 0.140158, 1.05936, 0.0964287, 0.116732}, {0.0667764, 0.0489254, 
 0.137437, 0.0962666, 0.0882702, 0.0704283, 0.0807027, 1.05768, 
 0.101375}, {0.0824603, 0.11258, 0.135069, 0.110204, 0.102288, 
 0.103722, 0.0453945, 0.0473116, 1.10549}};
n = 9;
d = 0.12;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges ->True];
Ga = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*g;
sa = SparseArray[Ga];
weightedG = 
  Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> i}, 
  VertexSize -> .3];
SetProperty[weightedG, 
  VertexLabels -> {i_ :> 
  Placed[PropertyValue[{weightedG, i}, VertexCapacity], Center]}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
weightedG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
   DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCapacity -> {i_ :> i}];

countries = {"UnitedStates", "Russia", "China"};
```

**1.** Use the coordinates of three largest cities in each country as vertex coordinates for the three sectors:

```
vertexcoordinates = Join @@ (Reverse[#["Coordinates"]] & /@ 
       Entity["Country", #]["LargestCities"][[;; 3]] & /@ countries);

gr1 = Show@SetProperty[weightedG, {VertexCoordinates -> vertexcoordinates, 
     VertexLabels -> {i_ :> Placed[PropertyValue[{weightedG, i}, VertexCapacity], 
         Center]}}];

GeoGraphics[{Red, Opacity[.5], AbsolutePointSize[15], 
  Point /@ vertexcoordinates, Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  Entity["Country", #]["Polygon"] & /@ countries}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoBackground -> "Coastlines", 
 GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", Epilog -> gr1[[1]], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

**2.** Use three random points inside the country polygon as vertex coordinates:

```
SeedRandom[1]
randomvc = Join @@ (Reverse /@ 
  RandomPoint[Polygon@Entity["Country", #]["Polygon"][[1, 1]], 3] & /@ countries);

gr2 = Show@SetProperty[weightedG, {VertexCoordinates ->  randomvc, 
    VertexLabels -> {i_ :> 
       Placed[PropertyValue[{weightedG, i}, VertexCapacity], 
        Center]}}]; GeoGraphics[{Red, Opacity[.5], 
  AbsolutePointSize[15], Point /@ randomvc, Opacity[1], 
  EdgeForm[Gray], Entity["Country", #]["Polygon"] & /@ countries}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoBackground -> "Coastlines", 
 GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", Epilog -> gr2[[1]], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice alternatives.